# How to disable Raygun.io client via app configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, raygun, raygun.io

I have Raygun.io client integrated into the latest release of our server application that is run by the enterprise customers. Unfortunately, some of them may not like to send any data outside of their network and they will want to disable the Raygun.io client.

My question is if there is anything already in Raygun.io library that allows them to disable it by editing `<server>.exe.config` file or I need to roll out my own implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [their .NET client implementation](https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4net), you have a couple of configuration options via the `<server>.exe.config`, like excluding errors by their HTTP status code,

```
<RaygunSettings apikey="YOUR_APP_API_KEY" excludeHttpStatusCodes="418" />
```

or removing sensitive data from the HTTP request,

```
<RaygunSettings apikey="YOUR_APP_API_KEY" ignoreFormFieldNames="password" />
```

but nothing like an enable/disable switch.

You would have to add your own app setting `<add key="EnableRaygunLogging" value="True" />` and programmatically check the value when using the Raygun.io client.

Answer (score 2):

It was suggested by a Raygun moderator on [this forum](https://raygun.io/forums/thread/16119) that you can just leave the API Key empty to disable it.

```
<raygunSettings apiKey="" />
```